# Amazon RDS Oracle : impdp REMAP_SCHEMA

Tags: oracle, amazon-web-services, oracle11g, amazon-rds

I'm trying to import some data into Amazon AWS using the instructions from [the official tutorial](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Oracle.Procedural.Importing.html#Oracle.Procedural.Importing.DataPump). I've uploaded the dump file to the RDS machine successfully.

The last step is doing the actual import using the `impdp` Oracle utility. If I don't remap the schema it works great. However I do need to remap the schema and I'm running into issues.

If I run `impdp` with the `REMAP_SCHEMA` option I get :

```
ORA-39122: Unprivileged users may not perform REMAP_SCHEMA remappings.
```

After googling, it looks like the only way to enable this is :

```
grant imp_full_database to MY_USER;
```

But RDS rejects this with :

```
ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1
ORA-20997: "IMP_FULL_DATABASE" grants not allowed
ORA-06512: at "RDSADMIN.RDSADMIN", line 51
ORA-06512: at line 2
```

This definitely looks like something that has been deliberately enforced at the RDS level.

**Do you know if there is a way to remap a schema when using RDS and impdp ?**

Comment: [Unprivileged users can perform schema remaps only if their schema is the target schema of the remap.](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/dp_import.htm#SUTIL3187). So is the `impdp` command connecting as the target schema/user?

Comment: I don't think there is a way, that `GRANT` is necessary for `REMAP_SCHEMA` and if RDS has disabled that feature then I don't see any other option.

Comment: @AlexPoole as you said, I was using another user. Everything is fine now. Thx !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alex (see comment on my question) is right. [Unprivileged users can perform schema remaps only if their schema is the target schema of the remap](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/dp_import.htm#SUTIL3187)

So the steps I've taken are :

```
create user MY_USER identified by ****;
grant create session, create table to MY_USER;
alter user MY_USER quota unlimited on users;
-- both read and write are needed
grant read, write on directory data_pump_dir to MY_USER;
grant execute on dbms_datapump to MY_USER;
```

And then:

```
impdp MY_USER/psswd@server DUMPFILE=file.dmp DIRECTORY=DATA_PUMP_DIR \
remap_tablespace=original_tablespace:users \
remap_schema=original_user:MY_USER
```